# Appium press call back button make the app crash on android

Tags: android, selenium, android-uiautomator, python-appium

I have searched the same symptom but cannot be fixed.
I use appium to do some automation with UiAutomator1.

Every call the back button

`driver.keyevent(4)`

The app crash(or exit) and goes to the Android home page.
The log seems normal.
[image: log as image]

However, a click back button on the emulator is fine.

There is no way to go to that page without click back button.

How can I click back button, or get the view name and go to that view directly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on **BACK** button in android, I think the following code will work fine:

```java
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
```

reference:
http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/keys/press-keycode/

Comment: Thank you for reply, but i still get same error on pressKeyCode

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix it.
However, i use another way to fix my problem.

```
self.driver.start_activity("xxx", "xxx")
```

It may not the best solution, but it can go to the view directly

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem some time back, solved using this :

```
driver.navigate().back();
```

or you can also try using this :

```
driver.back();
```